# Physically impossible to find the constant

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can we show 
$$
g(a) = \int _a^{a+1} 
\left\{x\right\} \cdot 
\left(1 - \left\{x\right\} \right)\:dx = \mbox{const}
$$
where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Comment: A definite integral will not introduce a constant, where do you expect one?

Comment: In my book say $g\left(a\right)=\int _a^{a+1}\left\{x\right\}\cdot \left(1-\left\{x\right\}\right)\:dx\:is\:a\:constant$ why?

Comment: Are you asking why g(a) is a constant?

Comment: @user222031: It looks like OP may be asking why $g(a)$ does not depend on $a$

Comment: I suppose If in my book say g(a) is a constant derivate will be 0

Comment: To say it's "physically" impossible is nonsensical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find the integer $k$ between $a$ and $a+1$ (if $a$ is an integer, choose $k=a$). Now split the integral:

$$\int_a^{a+1} \{ x \} (1-\{ x \}) dx = \int_a^k \{ x \} (1-\{ x \}) dx + \int_k^{a+1} \{ x \} (1-\{ x \}) dx.$$

Now on each of these intervals you can make the substitution $u=\{ x \}$. (You must split the integral to make $f(x)=\{ x \}$ be continuously differentiable and injective.) Doing that and recombining the integrals you find that you have

$$\int_0^1 u (1-u) du.$$

Comment: @Lucas Correct.

Comment: @Lucas It is ultimately because the fractional part is always in $[0,1]$. In this case since you are integrating over an interval of length $1$, every possible value of the fractional part gets represented exactly once, so you wind up integrating from $0$ to $1$. The step I started with is necessary to deal with the fact that the values of the fractional part don't appear in order: the ones between $k-a$ and $1$ are to the left of $k$ while the ones between $0$ and $k-a$ are to the right of $k$.

Comment: @Lucas This isn't hard to see from the graph, which consists of two straight line segments of slope $1$ with a jump at $k$.

Comment: @Lucas I don't want to deal with the fractional part, so I want to make a substitution to remove it. Whenever you do this (at least in the standard calculus framework) you have to be sure that the function in the substitution (the $f$ for which $u=f(x)$) is continuously differentiable and injective on the interval in question. The function $f(x)=\{ x \}$ is *not* continuously differentiable and invertible on any interval containing an integer in the interior, but it is continuously differentiable and invertible on any other interval.

Comment: @Lucas (Cont.) So I split into two intervals, neither of which has an integer in the interior, and then do the substitution on each of those. Then when I recombine back in the $u$ variables I get the result I wrote. Sorry that I need to get back to my grading right now.

Comment: Ian, you say :"So I split into two intervals, neither of which has an integer in the interior"  and here: "if a is an integer, choose k=a" and after you split and we don't need an integer to be sure that substitution can happens... ( k=a, I think is integer )

Comment: @Lucas If $k=a$ then there is no need to split, $f(x)=\{ x \}$ is continuously differentiable and injective on an interval of the form $[k,k+1)$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But this case is absorbed into what I wrote, since $\int_a^a \{ x \} (1-\{ x \}) dx = 0$. Otherwise I split in such a way as to put the integer on the boundary of each subinterval, where it creates no problems. I notice that I made a phrasing error: it is not necessary to split to make the substitution injective, it is necessary to make it continuous, because $f(x)=\{ x \}$ has a jump discontinuity at $k$.

Answer (score 3):

Since both functions, $\{x\},$  and $1-\{x\}$ are periodic with the period $T=1$ then also periodic is $\{x\}(1-\{x\}).\ $  Then we can use the well-known fact for periodic function $f(x):$
*Integral*
$$\int\limits_{a}^{a+T}{f(x)}\,dx  $$
*does not depend on $a.$*
***Proof***
Denote $$I(a)=\int\limits_{a}^{a+T}{f(x)}\,dx.$$ Then
$$\dfrac{dI(a)}{da}=f(a+T) \dfrac{d(a+t)}{da}-f(a)\dfrac{da}{da}=f(a+t)-f(a)=0.$$

Comment: So $\int _a^{a+T}\:f\left(x\right)dx=F\left(a+T\right)-F\left(a\right)=0$ and does the reason why does not depend on a?

Comment: In general, the antiderivative of periodic function is not necessarily periodic. For example, the function $f(x)=1+\sin{x}$ is periodic, but its antiderivative $F(x)=x-\cos{x}$ isn't.